# Releasing a deleted but open log file

Tags: debian, postgresql

my Debian server disk maxed out because of a large postgresql log file and while I have deleted it, it is still held by postgresql. When I restart postgresql I get an error as the disk is full and the software cannot start. This is the file listed using lsof +L1:

```
COMMAND     PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE    SIZE/OFF NLINK    NODE NAME
testproxy 22712 postgres    2w   REG    8,1 15309393920     0 1184540 /tmp/postgresql-9.4-main.log (deleted)
```

I've tried some commands suggested in other threads but it's not working. Can anyone suggest how to remove this file, bearing in mind restarting postgresql is not working?

thanks!

Comment: the logfile seems to be held open by command `testproxy` (running as user postgres) not by postgres itself.  try killing `testproxy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, there is still a process (live or not) which has the file open.  If it is not a zombie, you can kill it explicitly (with the right permissions):

```
sudo kill -9 22712
```

Comment: `kill -9` is overkill.

Comment: That's it -- thanks a lot for the suggestion!

Answer (score 6):

You have a bigger problem than Out of Disk my friend!

This is a User Defined Function exploit which takes advantage of PostgreSQL's large objects. (lo_) functions.

On my server it is a trojan that creates a proxy to baby0119.com over port 80.  It was installed as your postgres user over your postgres port 5432.

Check your 'postgres' database for a function called 'exec111'. \df+ exec111.

Drop that function, tighten up your pg_hba.conf, firewall, etc.

Also, check your postgresql log for commands issued or ERRORs.

Files I found on my box in /tmp are:

- 6 Dec  7 11:37 sjkpppp
- 961472 Dec  7 16:36 testproxy6
- 8088 Dec  7 16:36 testproxy.so

If you have a web server running on the postgres server, check your web access logs, grep for 'proxytest' or proxy, etc.

Comment: Wow -- thanks for dropping by 1966Mustang! I indeed found both those things. Highly appreciate the warning!

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your help, we got the same problem. The question is still there how one can break our connection password ?

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you're feeling particularly venturesome, `gdb`!

```
% lsof | grep deleted | grep deleteme
% perl -E 'while(1){ say "om nom nom"; sleep 1 }' > deleteme & rm deleteme
[2] 15720
% lsof | grep deleted | grep deleteme                                     
perl      15720    jdoe42    1w      REG                8,2        0    5376141 /home/jdoe42/deleteme (deleted)
% gdb -q -p 15720
...
(gdb) call close(1)
$1 = 0
(gdb) quit
...
% lsof | grep deleted | grep deleteme
% jobs
[1]  - running    perl -E 'while(1){ say "om nom nom"; sleep 1 }' > deleteme
% kill %1
% 
[1]  + terminated  perl -E 'while(1){ say "om nom nom"; sleep 1 }' > deleteme
%
```

This however may or may not work, may break the program thus fiddled with in unexpected ways, cause hair loss, sudden use of Windows syndrome, *et cetera*. In other words, use at your own risk. Simply killing the program will most often be a vastly better option.

Key points are obtaining the file descriptor number (via the `lsof` or equivalent), which here is the `STDOUT_FILENO` (`1w` according to `lsof`) because that's what the shell redirected, and then to call [`close(2)`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man2/close.2) on that file descriptor. Files opened by the program itself will likely have higher descriptor numbers (three and up); the question shows that standard error is going to the `/tmp` file (which appears to be a local security flaw, to write a static filename under `/tmp` like that).

Answer (score 0):

1966Mustang's answer is right.

1. This is usually because your Postgres password is too weak.
2. Check your `pg_hba.conf`, if you trusted all IP to connect your Server.